# Video rendering taking 13 Hrs to render for a normal video less than 2 minute

Tags: after-effects, rendering

ASUS TUF Gaming FX505DT 15.6-inch FHD Laptop, Ryzen 7 3750H, GTX 1650 4GB GDDR5 Graphics (16GB RAM/512GB NVMe SSD/Windows 10/Stealth Black/2.20 Kg), FX505DT-BQ157T
Hi all above mentioned is the spec of my device. When i try to render after effects composition which is just  1.5 minutes duration it took me around 13 hours to complete. Dont know why this is happening. I did many searches in youtube to speed up the output video rendering. But none works out. Does any one know why this happening. All my drivers are up to date. There is no problem when iam Just previewing the videos in after effects but rendering part is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering speed depends on a lot of factors. Things that slow the render down include

- using a lot of CPU intensive effects,
- lots of CPU intensive precomps,
- effects which require multiple frames to be calculated, such as echo or time displacement,
- using many source layers, particularly high resolution sources that take time to read from disk,
- some effects are just dog slow because they've never been optimised that well,

and lastly, but probably most importantly:

- memory issues: if you run out of RAM then it starts swapping to the hard drive, which even on a fast SSD is an order of magnitude slower than memory, so even simple compositions will take an inordinate amount of time.